# Custom spotting the locations on Google Map V2 with longitude and latitude of the place in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

I want to spot **50 places for test purpose in Google Map v2 android**.For example I have the database of 50 Restaurants which are newly opened but don't have their existence on Google Map V2 Android.I don't want to use Google Places API to fetch the restaurants list
For instance I have the information **Restaurant Name="ABC",Longitude="0.5555",Latitude="0.7455"** and this **Restaurant ABC doesn't exist on Google Map neither I can get it from Google Places API**.

Is there any possibility to post this information and spot on google Map V2 using Android?

Comment: just plot them on the map

Comment: What will be the mechanism to plot them on map.Can you tell me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the markers data from the database to a `ArrayList`, and loop on the array list to put all of those markers on the map this way, get the instance of the map:

```
SupportMapFragment smf = (SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview);
        if (smf != null) {
            map = smf.getMap();
        }
```

And then plot the markers:

```
double lat;
double lng;
String name;
String address;

for (MarkerData data: markersList)
{
    lat = data.getLat();
    lng = data.getLng();
    name = data.getName();
    address = data.getAddress();

    Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
    .title(name)
    .snippet(address)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_icon)));
}
```